# checking the zone config for all zone at once

Tags: server, dns, bind

I have hundreds of zone files and one of them has an error, but I don't know which.

Is there a way to check for errors using `named-checkzone domain-name file-name` command on all the files at once, or do I have to go through each file one at a time?

Comment: You would have to go one-by-one - there is no "Check all zones for errors" command.  You'd need to run that one file at a time.